# Searching for this chapter style

Tags: chapters

I'd like to use the chapter style of the screenshot below, but I don't know its name (and package ?); I've been searching for a long time, but couldn't find any clue...
I hope someone knows this style !
Regards.
[image: What's the name/package of this chapter style ??]

Comment: where did the image come from, do you know if it is made with latex at all?

Comment: It is 100% latex for sure, it's one of my past lectures.

Comment: @EWna Did you write the lecture notes, if not who did you get them from?

Comment: My teacher gave me these notes, but printed. I had no access to the pdf or the tex files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I (finally!) found a satisfying answer; I'm posting it for those who'd like to know.

```
\usepackage{titlesec} % For the \titleformat
\usepackage{fancybox} % For the \ovalbox
\setlength{\fboxsep}{10pt} % Sets the padding of the boxes
\cornersize{.3} % Sets the roundness of the corners of the \ovalbox

% Syntax: \titleformat{command}[shape]{format}{label}{sep}{before}[after]
\titleformat{\chapter}
    [hang] % Places the chapter name next to the number, (default: 'display')
    {\Huge\bfseries}
    {\Ovalbox{\thechapter}}
    {10pt}
    {\Huge}
 
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{20pt} % Sets the margins of the chap. title block
```

It seems to do the trick very well !

[image: Example of the searched chapter style with my own document]

Comment: I really like this style of notes. Do you have a link to the original set? Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I understand. Do you mean PDF documents? In that case it's impossible, they're not available online.